# Splunk queries: filter by _meta fields

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

### Context

I have a bunch of application servers I would like monitor using **Splunk**. Servers on every environment run the same applications. Looking for a way to tag this information in order to easily disentangle *stage* servers from *prod* server in my dashboards, I came across this trick while reading forums.

`inputs.conf` of *forwarders* on **production** machines

```
[default]
_meta = env::prod
```

`inputs.conf` of *forwarders* on **stage** machines

```
[default]
_meta = env::stage
```

With this trick, I end up with a `env` field in my parsed data.

```sql
index=* | stats count by env

| env    | count |
|:------:|:-----:|
| stage  |2415686|
| prod   |55677  |
```

### Issue

I can't filter on `env`

```sql
index=* logLevel="ERROR" projectName != "null" env="prod" | stats count(_raw) by projectName
```

Why is that so?

Comment: *usually* this is accomplished by looking at the `host` - presuming you have a naming convention that indicates different environments, it's great

Comment: Yeah but I am in the case of multiple loaded balanced systems. A nice way to select every machines from the same environment is a plus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, in my case, `env` was merely a **tag** (which are not indexed by default). In order to index them, you need to explicitly ask for it in `fields.conf`

```
[env]
INDEXED = true
```